# How to change Form::open to html view in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I use laravel 5.1. How to change it:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductController@store']) !!}
```

to

Html form:

```
<form action=""></form>
```

I've tried to do:

```
<form action="{{ route('action' => 'ProductController@store') }}"></form>
```

But I didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try Naming the route in your routes.php file and then call the named route. Example, in your routes.php file add the route like so:

```
Route::post('some/path', ['as'=>'mySuperCoolName', 'uses'=>'Controller@actionFunction']);
```

and then in your form call the route by name:

With HTML generator:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'mySuperCoolName']) !!}
```

With regular HTML:

```
<form action="{{ route('mySuperCoolName') }}"></form>
```

Even if this does not work, it's better practice to used named routes so I'd recommend using these anyways.

Best of Luck!

Comment: This isn't an option , you too hard . I need a simple

Comment: Why is this not an option? This is the correct method!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `url` helper with the parameter of your route:

**Example**

```
<form action="{{ url('/') }}">
```

this would generate

```
<form action="/">
```

Of course you need to have the proper route in your `routes.php`

```
Route::post('/', 'ProductController@index');
```

Comment: I have 'ProductController', In the ProductController has method store   public function store(PublishProductRequest $requestData)
    {
        $product = new Product;
        $product->title = $requestData['title'];
        $product->description = $requestData['description'];
        $product->full_description = $requestData['full_description'];
        $product->save();

        return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer next time just update your original post please. I updated my answer with the necessary infos.

Comment: Okey, I have already tried "Route::post('/', 'ProductController@index');".
I have a form that sends the data to the database